# Wait until a file is finished copying when using a directory watcher in Go

Tags: linux, file, go

I'm using the golang watcher package to watch a directory of files.
https://github.com/radovskyb/watcher

The only issue is that the Create event is triggered when a file begins being copied/moved, not when it's actually ready. I was wondering if there was a neat way in Go to sort of wait after the create event until the file is no longer being written to before continuing on.

I suppose this waiting would most likely have to be done in a goroutine to not block any other file events.

Simple example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "time"

        "github.com/radovskyb/watcher"
)

func main() {
        w := watcher.New()

        w.FilterOps(watcher.Create, watcher.Write)

        go func() {
                for {
                        select {
                        case event := <-w.Event:
                                fmt.Println(event) // Print the event's info.
                                if event.Op == watcher.Create {
                                    // HERE WE DO STUFF
                                    doStuff(event)
                                }
                        case err := <-w.Error:
                                log.Fatalln(err)
                        case <-w.Closed:
                                return
                        }
                }
        }()

        // Watch this folder for changes.
        if err := w.Add("./files/"); err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }


        // Start the watching process - it'll check for changes every 100ms.
        if err := w.Start(time.Millisecond * 100); err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you going to know that the *entire* file was copied correctly?  Are you just assuming it will be?

Comment: Assumption @AndrewHenle unless you know of any other way

Answer (score 2):

The library you are using cannot do what you are asking.  The docs say:

> watcher is a Go package for watching for files or directory changes (recursively or non recursively) **without using filesystem events**, which allows it to work cross platform consistently.

When I first saw this question, I thought it would be easily solved by waiting for the "file close" event, which will occur when a file copy is complete.  But because the library you're using refuses to utilize platform-specific APIs, it cannot know this information.

You can solve your problem more efficiently and accurately by using `inotify`.  There is https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify but it does not support the `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15406).  Perhaps you can use it as inspiration to write your own `inotify` wrapper which does support `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` (and probably little else).

One notable limitation of `inotify` is that it will not work with NFS, but there are limitations with `watcher` too (and you wouldn't want to use its polling mechanism on a network share, at least not rapidly).

Comment: fsnotify looks like it could work, however it also only has a Create event. How could I know when the file is closed using it?

Comment: @Chaos: Indeed!  I just realized that while `fsnotify` uses `inotify`, it does so in a non-customizable way that does not support `unix.IN_CLOSE_WRITE` (the event name you'd want).  There is a note about this here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15406 .  I guess you will need to write your own code using `inotify`, perhaps using `fsnotify` as a starting point.  I'll edit my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks, do you perhaps any example of the inotify package? Does the FILE CLOSE event make sense for my use case? It would be triggered for files being being editted as well, not just for initial copies right?

Comment: @Chaos: see here for one possible inotify package for Go: https://godoc.org/lukeshu.com/git/go/libgnulinux.git/inotify .  I suggest using the "create" event to look for new files, and the "file close write" event to look for files which are "finished."  If you see both events for a file, there's a good chance it is one  you want.

Answer (score 1):

fkocik has committed a PR which implements IN_CLOSE_WRITE, and it does work for me on Linux.

[ADDED: CloseWrite event support](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/pull/252)

NB: the code is not present in the master branch yet, you nee retrieve it manually.